# how to show data from database on map view using kml files in iOS app

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview, kml

I have huge amount of location records in database and I want to show my locations data on map view using KML for generating visualizing annotations. How can I show those visualized effects on map view? Please give me suggestions to work with KML for iOS apps....

Answer (score 6):

See the Apple KMLViewer sample code here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html

It shows how to display KML files on top of an MKMapView.

Also see the following two projects on github. I've used them both to parse KML and display the results on a map. SimpleKML is good for most uses. KML Framework has (last time I checked), a more complete implementation of the KML standard. Either should be good for simple KML placemarks and overlays.

https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML

https://github.com/FLCLjp/iOS-KML-Framework

Comment: i need to do same with google maps any suggestion on how can i do that?